#  A question on countably compact space

Tags: gn.general-topology, compactness

A  regular space $X$ is

1. star compact (which implies pseudocompact)
2. with $G_\delta$-diagonal
3. star countable
4. first countable
5. $e(X)\le \aleph_0$ ( in fact it implies star countable)
6. $|X|=\aleph_1$
7. Cech-complete
8. under CH

My question is this: Must $X$ be countably compact?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: I'm sure you already know that if $X$ is normal and pseudocompact then $X$ is countably compact. I don't know enough about these other conditions you list to know whether or not they can get you from regular to normal. I know that paracompactness is enough. Any chance your space $X$ is paracompact? Or that it's locally metrizable?

Comment: It may be not at all. 

Answer (score 3):

Please cheek 5I in gilman jerison Book (Rings of continuous functions). I am not sure. Since I dont put comments, I put this as an answer.

Comment: What is meaning of "5l"?

Comment: Exercise 5I in Book of Gilman jerison. It is a completely regular, pseduocompact, non-normal, satisfies the first countably axiom, and every subset of this space is $G_{\delta}. But is not contably compact. Because, has an infinite discrete zero-set.

Comment: +1: Hopefully you can leave comments soon

Comment: @Ali: could you give me a link of the book, so I can download it?

Comment: Ok, you can downloaded this book of BookFinder and search ring of continuous fuctions.